# как убрать полоску вокруг tkinter.Menu?

Tags: python, tkinter

Как убрать полоску вокруг виджета `Menu` в `tkinter`? я пробовал `bd=0` и `borderwidth=0` но это не помогло
вот код:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
def test():
    print("test")
def do_popup(event):
    menu = tkinter.Menu(root, tearoff = 0, bg='#11b384', fg='black', activebackground='#12cc97', activeforeground='black', relief='solid', borderwidth=0, bd=0)
    menu.add_command(label="Item 1", command=test)
    menu.add_command(label="Item 2", command=test)
    try:
        menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    finally:
        menu.grab_release()

root.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event: do_popup(event))
root.mainloop()
```

меня смущает вот эта рамка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите < https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921360/how-to-remove-the-border-of-a-tkinter-optionmenu-widget>

Comment: @СергейКох в данном примере он использует Menu, а в ссылке которую вы скинули используеться OptionMenu

Comment: вы имеете ввиду отступ от зеленого фона и до бордера?

Comment: да, отступ от зеленого до бордера, и желательно еще покрасить сам бордер как то

Comment: Среди атрибутов отсутствуют нужные(или я проглядел), поэтому навряд ли это возможно

Comment: у меня вопрос такой...а какое у вас окружение...опишите его, пожалуйста...а то я не могу воспроизвести ваши рамки https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd9JS.png

Comment: Данная рамка есть только на Windows 10, этот же код запущенный на KDE Plasma рамки не имеет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цвет границы меню задается цветом фона меню. Если вы хотите, чтобы цвет рамки отличался от цвета фона меню, вы должны установить цвет фона для каждой записи отдельно.

Для толщины границы просто установите значение в пикселях в атрибуте «граница» и тип рельефа «плоский», чтобы tkinter не создавал псевдо-3D с заданным цветом.

Затем, учитывая изображение выше, мы создадим окно меню с черным фоном в меню и красной рамкой:

```
import tkinter

def command():
    pass

def main():
    w = tkinter.Tk()
    menu = tkinter.Menu(w, background="black", foreground="red")
    file_menu = tkinter.Menu(menu, background="red", foreground="red", relief="flat", border=8, tearoff=0)
    opcoes = "Contas User  Usuários  Email Services  Login Cad. Usuário  Variáveis do Sistema  Sair".split("  ")
    for opcao in opcoes:
        file_menu.add_command(label=opcao, command=command, background="black")
    menu.add_cascade(label="Cadastro", menu=file_menu)

    w.config(menu=menu)
    return w

main()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

(этот код предназначен для Python 3 — в Python 2 просто измените «tkinter» на «Tkinter» во всех точках)

Если вы хотите изменить цвет фона или какой-либо другой атрибут пункта меню после его создания, вы должны использовать метод в меню:

```
file_menu.entry_config(0, ...)
```

Где 0 — индекс нужной записи.

### [Оригинал](https://itqna.net/questions/13201/change-border-color-and-size-tkinter-menu#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20the%20border,3D%20with%20the%20given%20color.)